# Material-ui typography themeoption useNextVariants type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm getting error :

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'useNextVariants' does not exist in type 
>   'TypographyOptions | ((palette: Palette) => TypographyOptions)'

while trying to use `useNextVariants` in `themeOptions`.

```
export const themeOptions: ThemeOptions = {
typography: {
    useNextVariants: true,
    // more properties
    } }

const theme = createMuiTheme(themeOptions);
```

I'm using latest version of material-ui. I tried to change version but it seems it hasn't been defined in TypographyOptions in any version.

Comment: Just remove `useNextVariants`. It was removed in v4 (v4 unconditionally behaves the same as v3 with `useNextVariants = true`).

Comment: @RyanCogswell am getting it at a number of other places too, like: while overriding MuiButton (flatPrimary) and MuiTypography (headline)

Comment: It sounds like you haven't gone through the v3 to v4 migration guide: https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/

Comment: The `flat` button variant [no longer exists](https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/#button) and neither does [headline](https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/#typography).

Comment: @RyanCogswell wew! thank a lot, I hadn't gone through it tbh , i didn't know these many things have changed and since and new to TS and using Themes in Mui ... not smart enough to figure it out myself rn. thanks.